# How do I bypass/workaround dialogflow 256 character limit for detect intent text input length?

Tags: ivr, dialogflow-cx, twilio-studio, twilio-flow

I'm new to dialogflow and was messing around trying to get a basic IVR working.

I'm trying to get a long response and was using the "@sys.any" entity to take in the response, but it has a maximum detect intent text input length of 256 characters total and so it cuts off the user. I want it to act as a listener and just transcribe the speech until either the user stops speaking for some time or until they press a key on the keypad. I'm integrating Dialogflow with Twilio using Studio Flow, so maybe there's a way to achieve this through the Twilio integration if it's not possible with Dialogflow. Basically, I just want to find a way to bypass/workaround the character limit. The limit is for detecting intents. I don't want it to detect any intents I just want it transcribe for me. Doesn't need to be real time either.